# Reusing LCD TFT Panel

Tags: lcd, layout, pins, display, tft

Recently I have taken an old MP4 apart so I could maybe reuse some of it's parts. One of them is the touchscreen panel, but the big problem is, I don't know the pin layout of it. Is there a way I could figure it out?
[image: The Display: Foxlink 8287-0269-5080 REV1.0 (4108)]

Foxlink 8287-0269-5080 REV1.0 (4108)

After taking some time I have tried some things and could identify 9 pins:

```
01-(nothing?)
02-
03-
04-
05-
06-
07-
08-
09-
10-
11-
12-
13-
14-
15-
16-
17-
18-
19-
20-
21-
22-
23-
24-
25-
26-Touchpanel Y-
27-Touchpanel X-
28-Touchpanel Y+
29-Touchpanel X+
30-LED A Backlight
31-LED K1 Backlight
32-LED K2 Backlight
33-LED K3 Backlight
34-LED K4 Backlight
35-Connected with the C1
36-Linked with 35
37-(nothing?)
```

I still have the MP4 board which I can hook up on a 3.7V source (battery output) and maybe measure the output of the pins. But even with the measurement I don't know what pin does what. I would appreciate if someone could explain how to analyze the panel and maybe identify some other pins from these pictures:[image: Front][image: Back]

I have been able to find a similar panel [here](http://vrtp.ru/index.php?showtopic=1120&st=2310), but sadly I can't read the language. A user has posted his work there which looks like this:[image: Foxlink 8287-0249-8080 REV1.0]

One more question what I would have is: how can I find out where ground (GND) is? For the most simple analysis I need to be able to connect my sources to the GND pin. Is there a way to figure it out on the panel?

Thank you in advance!

P.S. Sorry if I made some kind mistake, I am new to this part of StackExchange.

Comment: How's your Russian? [Link](http://vrtp.ru/index.php?showtopic=1120&st=2310)

Comment: Use Google Translate.  It does a surprisingly good job.

Comment: It looks like the OP beated you by just 12 minutes into discovering that very same link. :)

Comment: I can speak Bosnian so I recognize some words... Sadly the link shows the Foxlink 8287-0249-8080, which has a different pin layout. But from the picture there I figured out where the backlight pins are.